# How to pass an argument which starts with $ to ant from cygwin terminal?

Tags: ant, cygwin, special-characters

I am running an `ant` command from Cygwin terminal where I am signing my exe.
I am running a command similar to

```
ant -Dpassword=$abcde
```

Here `$abcde` is my password but when I run an `echo`, it shows the password as blank.

How can I pass `$` as part of my argument so `ant` can process it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Unix shell, the `$` sign is used to identify a shell variable.   To prevent parameter expansion due to it being treated as a variable, you need to either:

- escape it (by prepending a backslash)
- or wrap it in **single** quotes (quoting removes the special meaning of certain characters such as `$`)

Either of the following should work:

```
ant -Dpassword=\$abcde
ant -Dpassword='$abcde'
```

*Edit:* It seems that `ant` treats the dollar sign as a special character. Assuming that a backslash can be used by `ant` for escaping special characters, both the backslash and the dollar character should be passed on to `ant` by the shell:

```
ant -Dpassword='\$abcde'
```